# MySQL Query assistance - I'm baffled

Tags: mysql

Wondering in anyone can assist me with a couple of queries which have cropped up in a project. The project is a database of people and their attendance of training courses.

There are a few tables...

```
Users (with UserID and Username)

Teachers (with TeacherID and TeacherName)

Courses (with CourseID, CourseName, CourseDate and TeacherID) - this one relates to which teacher took which course

Attendances (with UserID and CourseID) - this one relates which user attended which course
```

What the client is after is firstly selecting all the users who have NOT attended a specific teachers' courses. In other words, if they have been on a course with the specified teacher, they will not be shown.

Secondly, the client wants the same query as the first but also limiting it to the last 6 months. In other words, selecting all the users who have NOT attended a specific teachers' courses within the last six months.

This one has got me a bit baffled so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: what queries have to tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
select username 
from user 
where userid not in 
(select userid 
from attendance a, course c 
where a.courseid = c.courseid and teacherid = {Value})
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users INNER JOIN attendances ON database.id = attendances.RespondentID LEFT JOIN events ON attendances.EventID = events.EventID AND events.ModID = 57 WHERE events.EventID IS NULL GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY `date_updated` desc LIMIT 0,50

Comment: The above seems to be working apart from one thing. If a user has attended an event by the particular moderator and an another event by another moderator, it still appears on the list of result. I.e. if they attended an event by ModID=57, they should be removed from the list regardless of if they have attended an event with another ModID.

This is getting curiouser and curiouser!

Rik

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.username
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN attendance a
  ON u.userid = a.userid
LEFT JOIN course c
  ON c.courseid = a.courseid
  AND teacherid = [teacher id value]
WHERE a.courseid IS NULL
```

Might be faster than a NOT IN subquery.  MySQL used to be (and possibly still is) bad at optimizing subqueries.